# log4j2 syslog appender truncates first word in log message

Tags: java, log4j2, syslog-ng

I am using log4j2 to send logs to syslog using syslog appender in log4j2.xml file. The problem that I am facing is that the first word in the log message is truncated. You can use two formats in syslog appender RFC 5424 and BSD. When I use BSD, then the first word in the message is truncated. When I use RFC 5424, then there is too much unwanted information printed. Here is my log4j2.xml file. In this case I am using BSD format as it defaults to BSD. I don't know why or how it truncates the first word.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SS:SS]} [%-5p] %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Syslog name="syslogAppender" host="localhost" port="514" protocol="UDP" 
                facility="LOCAL0" id="myApp" />
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="syslogAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Output in log file:

```
[2021-04-09T18:01:02+00:00][info] unavailiblity window to station
```

Expected Output:

```
[2021-04-09T18:01:02+00:00][info] Sending unavailiblity window to station
```

I am not sure what the problem is. If I use RFC 5424 then it prints too much unwanted information and I have no way to format it the way I want it. With RFC 5424 format, it produces the following output:

```
[2021-04-09T15:52:37+00:00][info] 2021-04-09T15:52:37.912Z ip-172-31-28-58 /home/user 24253 - - Sending unavailability window to station
```

I want to use the simple format. The BSD format works for me only if it does not truncate the first word.

Thanks

Comment: This is very confusing. The log events you show above all look like they are coming from the console appender as they start with the date and log level both in brackets. Neither BSD or RFC 5424 records will look like that.

Comment: I have a syslog-ng.conf file that formats the BSD message. 

destination d_smart_terminal_event_scheduler { file("/data/logs/scheduler/scheduler.log" template("[$ISODATE][$LEVEL] $MSG\r\n") create-dirs(yes)); };

When I use BSD format, I only get a truncated message in $MSG macro

Answer (score 0):

PatternLayout is the problem, use any other layout like RFC5424Layout etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).